# Android: Video Picker options

Tags: android, video

What is difference between these two options to pick video files and which one is recommended.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO);
```

and this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO);
```

Also, the second option having an issue in Nougat, it doesn't show any videos though it shows gallery. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

- by this code snippet will show dialog with choosing item Explorer(File explorer),Gallery,Videos file,and other softer that support to select video file while choosing complete action using Dialog item
- intent.setType("video/*"); will show only videos file

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
  MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO);
  ```

  - but this code snipped not show Explorer(File explorer),video file while choosing complete action using Dialog item
  - intent.setType("video/*"); will show only videos file